# How do I return a valid input from scanner?

Tags: java, regex

I gave up. I'm trying to figure out why my code is returning the first (incorrect) value.

For instance:

```
public static String lastName() {

    System.out.println("Last Name: ");
    String lastName = input.nextLine();
    String dataCheck = "[a-zA-Z]{1,77}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(dataCheck);
    Matcher patternMatcher = pattern.matcher(lastName);

    if(!patternMatcher.matches()){
        do{
            System.out.println("Incorrect input:\n"
                    + "1) Shorten the first name less than 77 characters;\n"
                    + "2) Only alphabet characters are allowed (no numbers or special characters.)\n\n"
                    + "Please enter Last Name: ");
            lastName();

        }
            while (!patternMatcher.matches());

    }
    return lastName;
}
public static void recall(String lastName){
    System.out.println(lastName);
}
```

What happens is if I enter an incorrect input, the scanner "stores" the first input and only uses it; if the input is correct, it continues. Research so far has told me to scrap the regex and just use input.hasNextLine(). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a recursive call, but not using the result... so once you come out of the loop, you're just returning the `lastName` variable from the top-most stack frame If you change this:

```
lastName();
```

to this:

```
return lastName();
```

then it *might* work. It's not entirely clear to me, because the code structure is unclear to me.

Fundamentally, it's not clear why you're recursing *and* looping at the same time. That feels like a very bad idea to me. Work out what you want to do on iteration (probably: display options; read a line; check the line) and put all of that inside the loop. So something like (pseudo-code):

```
do {
    display-menu
    ask-for-input  
} while (test-to-check-it's-not-valid)
```

Additionally, I'd revisit your naming - something like `getLastName()` or `readLastName()` would be clearer for the method than just `lastName()` - particularly as you have a local variable called `lastName` within the method.

Comment: It worked! I didn't know you can return a method! I definitely have code to modify. Thank you!!

Comment: @user130110: It's not returning a method - it's returning the value that the method call returned. If that's new to you, I would *strongly* recommend you put down regular expressions, and just learn a bit more of the core of the language for a while. Also even if the small modification worked, that doesn't mean it's the best approach - please read the rest of the answer carefully.

Comment: @user130110: That's absolutely the right approach - but I'd say that it's worth leaving regular expressions (which are relatively complex, with a complex API) until after learning the core bits of the language. Best of luck :)